# How to format C code in Visual Studio Code with GNUI formatting conventions?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a C project in Visual Studio Code and I would like to use GNU formatting in the project. Is there any extension to achieve this or any way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [C/C++ extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) has [ClangFormat](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) included with it, and there is a  setting called `C_Cpp.clang_format_style` that allows you to set the formatting to select options including GNU:

[image: vs code clang format style setting]

In your case, you would want to set this particular setting to `GNU`.

Settings JSON:

```json
{
   "C_Cpp.clang_format_style": "GNU"
}
```